# Convert origin of view in child view controller to parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, coordinate-transformation

Here's my basic layout (VC = view controller):

```
VC1
 -> Container view with embedded VC2

    VC2 (child of VC1)
     -> theView
```

I want to get the location of `theView` in terms of `VC1` so I can present a new view controller (`VC3`) modally on top of `VC1` (`VC3` has the same size and origin as `VC1`) and then place a new view in `VC3` right where `theView` is.

Right now, I'm able to get the location of `theView` within `VC2`, but I'm not sure how to translate to the parent `VC1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `convert` method to convert the coordinate system of a `UIView`'s frame to another view's coordinate system. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert) is the documentation of `convert` method.

It can be used like this:

```
self.view.convert(theView.frame, to: instanceOfVC1)
```

Comment: Okay so I think I was just misunderstanding what was wrong. This is a very simple solution and very similar to what I have for getting the desired origin when I don't have to deal with the child view controller VC2. Thanks!

Comment: So here's my solution: let desiredOrigin = convert(theView.frame.origin, to: VC1.view) and I can get VC1 by calling VC2.parentViewController if needed (it's needed in my case).